# Getting a single value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I am getting a response as an array in the following format:

```
Array
(
[refresh_token_expires_in": "0] => 
[api_product_list": "[ops-prod]] => 
[api_product_list_json": [
"ops-prod"
]] => 
[organization_name": "epo] => 
[developer.email": "sudham@gmail.com] => 
[token_type": "BearerToken] => 
[issued_at": "1568870621501] => 
[client_id": "F4GzALmoCfWXh] => 
[access_token": "MYjtqSlOI] => 
[application_name": "8ec0-872fa20cdc59] => 
[scope": "core] => 
[expires_in": "1199] => 
[refresh_count": "0] => 
[status": "approved] => 
[error] => 
)
```

when i run `print_r($token);` i am getting the proper response.

Now i need to grab the value of only "`access_token`". I am not sure how to do that. I tried with `$token['access_token'];` but its returning `null` value. Can anyone help me on the same.

The following is the json response:

```
  {"refresh_token_expires_in\": \"0":"","api_product_list\": \"[ops-prod]":"","api_product_list_json\": [\n \"ops-prod\"\n ]":"","organization_name\": \"epo":"","developer.email\": \"sudham@gmail.com":"","token_type\": \"BearerToken":"","issued_at\": \"1568871637352":"","client_id\": \"fxhYBIrh7BZHtcQeUIGF4GzALmoCfWXh":"","access_token\": \"HgARGtASwbcG":"","application_name\": \"2df9fbac-8ec0-872fa20cdc59":"","scope\": \"core":"","expires_in\": \"1199":"","refresh_count\": \"0":"","status\": \"approved":"","error":""}
```

Response

```
 a:14:{s:29:"refresh_token_expires_in": "0";s:0:"";s:30:"api_product_list": "[ops-prod]";s:0:"";s:44:"api_product_list_json": [
"ops-prod"
]";s:0:"";s:24:"organization_name": "epo";s:0:"";s:39:"developer.email":    "sudham@gmail.com";s:0:"";s:25:"token_type": "BearerToken";s:0:"";s:26:"issued_at": "1568871637352";s:0:"";s:45:"client_id": "4GzALmoCfWXh";s:0:"";s:44:"access_token": "ARGtASwbcG";s:0:"";s:56:"application_name": "46e2-8ec0-872fa20cdc59";s:0:"";s:13:"scope": "core";s:0:"";s:18:"expires_in": "1199";s:0:"";s:18:"refresh_count": "0";s:0:"";s:18:"status": "approved";s:0:"";}
```

oauth1.php

```
<?php
function read_token ($tokenname) {
    // read token file and return token variables array
    // if token not present or outdated create a new token and return new           token variables array
    $tokenfile="$tokenname.dat";
    $error='';
    if (file_exists($tokenfile)) {
        $token=unserialize(file_get_contents($tokenfile));
        // convert token issued time from windows (milliseconds) format to unix (seconds) format
        $tokentime=substr($token['issued_at'],0,-3);
        $tokenduration=$tokentime + $token['expires_in'] - 120;
        if ($tokenduration < time()) {
            $error.="token '$tokenname' expired.<br>\n";
        } else {
            $token['error']=$error;
        }
    } else {
        $error.="tokenfile '$tokenname' not found.<br>\n";
    }
    if ($error) {$token=create_token($tokenname);}
    return($token);
}

function create_token ($tokenname) {
    // set variables
    $tokenfile="$tokenname.dat";
    $error='';
    switch ($tokenname) {
    case 'OPSincidental':
        $ops_key='*******';
        $ops_secret='*******';
        break;
    default:
        $ops_key='*******';
        $ops_secret='*******';
        break;

    }
    $tokenUrl='https://ops.epo.org/3.2/auth/accesstoken';
    $tokenHeaders=array(
        'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($ops_key.':'.$ops_secret),
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    $tokenPostFields='grant_type=client_credentials';

    $curlOpts=array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $tokenUrl,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $tokenHeaders,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $tokenPostFields,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
    );

    // obtain token
    $token_request= curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($token_request, $curlOpts);
    if (!$ops_token_response=curl_exec($token_request)) {$error.=curl_error($token_request)."<br>\n";}
    curl_close($token_request);

    // process token
    $ops_token_split=explode(',', trim($ops_token_response,'{}'));
    foreach ($ops_token_split as $tokenval) {
        $tokenpair=explode(' : ', trim($tokenval));
        $token[trim($tokenpair[0],'"')]=trim($tokenpair[1],'"');
    }

    // write token data to file
    file_put_contents($tokenfile, serialize($token));

    // add error information to token array and return result
    $token['error']=$error;
    return($token);
}

?>
```

oauthmain.php

```
<?php
// obtain token
include_once('oauth1.php');
$token=read_token('OPSincidental');

//print json_encode($token);

if (!$token['error']) {
    echo "Token:<br>\n<PRE>"; print_r($token); echo "</PRE>";

    // prepare for sending data request
    $error='';

    $requestUrl='http://ops.epo.org/3.2/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/EP1000000/biblio';
    //$requestUrl='https://ops.epo.org/3.2/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/EP100000';
    $requestHeaders=array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$token['access_token'],
        'Host: ops.epo.org',
        'X-Target-URI: http://ops.epo.org',
        'Accept: application/xml',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive'
        );

    $curlOpts=array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $requestUrl,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $requestHeaders,
        //  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        //      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
        );
    // send request and collect data
    $ops_request= curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ops_request, $curlOpts);
    if (!$ops_response=curl_exec($ops_request)) { $error.=curl_error($ops_request)."<br>\n";}
    echo "curl options:<br>\n";
    echo "<PRE>";print_r($requestHeaders);echo "</PRE>";
    curl_close($ops_request);


    if ($error) {echo "Error:<br>\n$error";} else {echo "Result:<br>\n".htmlspecialchars($ops_response);}
} else {
    echo $token['error'];
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all you don't have any key named as `access_token` in your array, it is `access_token": "MYjtqSlOI` and second you have null values for all keys in your array, see nothing is printed after `=>` sign. So check your code from where you're getting this array, as it is not formatted properly.

Comment: Can you show the JSON which is the source of this array.

Comment: It should be something like this. `"access_token" => "MYjtqSlOI"`. So if you do `$token['access_token']` then you will get `MYjtqSlOI`

Comment: @Nigel, i have attached my json response and the source php of this array. Guess am making some mistake.

Comment: @Jithendra, i have attached my json response and the source php of this array. Guess am making some mistake.

Comment: @Jithendra what about the json response. Do you think its correct?

Comment: That JSON looks very strange. It looks like something tried to parse JSON, but did it wrong, so the quotes and `:` characters ended up as literal characters in  the keys and values.

Comment: @Barmar.. i am getting the response in a .dat file. i have just updated the question with the actual response i am getting in the .dat file. I have included it at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH I would recommend changing the way you store the token file - I would store the return value from the API directly to the file (you would be storing the JSON string).  At the moment you are trying to do your own `json_decode()` on the response - which is not correctly extracting the data anyway...

```
// Do not use this bit
// process token
// $ops_token_split=explode(',', trim($ops_token_response,'{}'));
// foreach ($ops_token_split as $tokenval) {
//    $tokenpair=explode(' : ', trim($tokenval));
//    $token[trim($tokenpair[0],'"')]=trim($tokenpair[1],'"');
// }
// Decode the values to $token
$token = json_decode($ops_token_split, true);

// Write JSON to token file
// write token data to file
file_put_contents($tokenfile, $ops_token_response);
```

Then to read the file, just `json_decode()` the contents of the file...

```
if (file_exists($tokenfile)) {
    $token=json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenfile), true);
```

Comment: Iam getting error  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Did you get a chance to run the script?

Comment: Sorry - I have changed the last line (missed the flag to say fetch arrays).  I've also added the line `$token = json_decode($ops_token_split, true);` as well.

Comment: Its working fine. Am getting the response properly. But a small error am getting i this line.  $token = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenfile), true);

 if (!$token['error']) {...........  The error states that Undefined index: error

Comment: Have a look at what values you have `var_dump($token);`.

Comment: there is no problem with the data. if (!$token['error']) { ..... i am getting error in this line.

Comment: It may be because the structure of the data, but you could always try `if (!empty($token['error']))`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `unserialize()` function to parse that response.

```
$ops_token_response = file_get_contents("filename.dat");
$token = unserialize($ops_token_response);
echo $token['access_token'];
```

Comment: Thx. Let me check it.

Comment: Actually i am using 2 php files to get an authentication from an API. I am not sure how to attach those 2 php files here

Comment: When i tried the changes give by you, am getting an error. unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Why is `$ops_token_response` an array? In your code you have `trim($ops_token_response,'{}')` and that requires a string, also.

Comment: i will attach those two php files with the question. I am not good at PHP so not getting an idea on where i am going wrong.

Comment: I've tried with this and keep on getting the error *unserialize(): Error at offset 145 of 589 bytes in*

Comment: Then there's a problem with the way the file was written. Maybe they tried to append multiple serialized arrays in the same file. That's not valid, just like you can't have multiple JSON strings in a file.

Comment: i have added the php files which is generating this token. The php files are oauth1.php and oauthmain.php. You can directly run the oauthmain.php to see the result.

Comment: @Nigel. i have added the php files which is generating this token. The php files are oauth1.php and oauthmain.php. You can directly run the oauthmain.php to see the result.

Comment: Its generating the token value. You can see line 20 in oauthmain.php. 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token['access_token'], I am not able to get the value 'access_token'

Comment: You seem to have completely changed the question. What happened to the original code that I was answering about?

Comment: I'm also getting an error when I try to unserialize the response you show in the question. Are you sure that's the correct contents of `OPSincidental.dat`?